# Session persistence with Zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, session

I'm having problems with storing variables in a `$_SESSION` variable.
I'm using Zend framework and building a 3 step application form. Now, when the first step is done, I store the data in MySQL database, and store the returned insert id in a session variable. Then I forward the page to another controller (step 2). When I forward the request, everything works fine and I can read the id from the session variable. But when I submit the second form (which has the same controller of step 2 as an action) the session is lost. I try to `var_dump` it, and it returns `NULL`.

Here's the code:

```
public function organizationAction()
{

    $this->view->vals="";
    $form=$this->getOrganizationForm();
    $this->aplid=$_SESSION['appid'];
    var_dump($_SESSION);
    $firsttime=$this->getRequest()->getParam('firsttime',0);

    //if(null==$this->aplid) $this->_forward('index','index');
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() && $firsttime==0) {
        if (!$form->isValid($_POST)) {
            // Failed validation; redisplay form
            $this->view->form = $form;
            return false;
        }
        var_dump($_SESSION);
        $values = $form->getValues();
        $db=new Util_Database();

        if($db->insertOrganization($values,$this->aplid))
            $this->_forward('final');
        else echo "An error occured while attempting to submit data. Please try agian";

    }


    $this->view->form=$form;
}
```

What is the problem here? I tried storing the `session_id` in the form, and then setting it before `session_start()`, but it starts a whole new session. Please help!

Comment: Dont use the $_SESSION variable directly(nor the php own session functions) when working with Zend framework, it's one of the things they advise the most. Zend has its own Session managment system with their corresponding classes. ... you should get vote down for not reading the docs :P

Comment: Didn't know they have a whole separate class for handling session. It is a downside of learning from a beginners' book and then immediately trying to make a real world application. Thanks for the heads up! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is going to help, because I'm not sure if something else might be happening in step 2. But here goes.
You might be inadvertently overwriting your session data. Here is what I came up with that might help give some ideas.

```
public function organizationAction() {

        $this->view->vals = "";
        $form = $this->getOrganizationForm();
        $db = new Util_Database();
        //This will only submit the form if the is post and firsttime == 0
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() && $this->getRequest()->getPost('firsttime') == 0) {
            //if form is valid set session and save to db
            if ($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())) {
                //We only want to initialize the session this time, if we do it
                //on the next pass we may overwrite the information.
                //initialize session namespace
                $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('application');
                //get values from form, validated and filtered
                $values = $form->getValues();
                //assign form value appid to session namespace
                $session->appid = $form->getValue('appid');
                //assign session variable appid to property aplid
                $this->aplid = $session->appid;
                if ($db->insertOrganization($values, $this->aplid))
                    $this->_forward('final');
                else
                    echo "An error occured while attempting to submit data. Please try agian";
            } else {
                //if form is not vaild populate form for resubmission
                //validation errors will display of form page
                $form->populate($this->getRequest()->getPost());
            }
        }
        //if not post display form
        $this->view->form = $form;
    }
```

P.S. If your gonna go ZF...Go ZF! :)